# Add a caret to a Regex Replacement

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to add a Carat to a Date in php

`preg_replace('(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/)', "/\^${1}/", $FileStream);`

So that `2000-01-01` becomes `^2000-01-01`;
Not working

Comment: The replacement should just be `"^$1"` the replacement is not a regexp.

Comment: Why don't you just prepend the ^ after replacing?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: His solution has more problems than just that. (See the Answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace(
  '/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/' ,
  "^$1" ,
  $FileStream
);
```

For reference, your solution contained the following mistakes:

1. When using a variable inside a string, and using curly brackets to contain it, you keep the `$` inside the brackets - `$varName` will work, so will `{$varName}`, but `${varName}` will fail.
2. With Regular Expressions, you are meant to have matching characters at the start and the end of the pattern you are matching - the Regular Expression Delimiters. That character is meant to be outside of any brackets you are using to capture a segment of the matched text. `/(.*)/` will work, but `(/.*/)` will try and treat the opening bracket as the delimiter and will, therefore, fail. (Plus it will try and find `/` characters at the start and end of the pattern.)

Comment: This retrieves the correct count $count=preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/', $FileStream, $matchesarray);But this doesnt add a carat.
        preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/', "^$1", $FileStream);

Comment: @mike628: What? The code I have provided DOES perform the replacement. I used `preg_replace()` - where did you get the `preg_match_all()` bit from? It's not in my code, so this feedback doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This is what I have: I have taken out the OR and also just hardcoded the string and It doesnt look like it works to me.$FileStream="structure and motivation. 2011-03-13^csacas^assascascvewd";
        $count=preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/', $FileStream, $matchesarray);
        preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/', "^$1", $FileStream);
        echo $FileStream;
        echo "Count= ".$count;

Comment: I put the count in there to check for matches. Have you tried the complete code above?

Comment: You need to assign the result of the replacement: `$FileStream=preg_replace(etc, etc, $FileStream);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/',
             "^$1", $FileStream);
```

---

Your current regex looks like:

```
'(/regex/)'
```

so `(`and `)` are being treated as regex delimiters and `/` and `/` are treated as literals.

But what you want is:

```
'/(regex)/'
```

so that `/` acts as delimiter and `(..)` capture the part of the string matching so that it can be used in the replacement as `$1` not `${1}` as you've used.